# How use vue.js create a Secondary navigation bar

Tags: vue.js

[image]I got the Json data and use it do a Secondary navigation bar with vue.js but i cant do finish it, this is my simple code,

`

```
<nav class="nav" id="nav">
    <ul class="navsBox"> 
      <!-- The primary navigation -->
      <template v-for="item in navItems" v-on="mouseover: mouseOver">
        <li><a href="#">{{item.gc_name}}</a></li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

`

```
  var vm = new Vue({
  el :'#nav',
  data: {
    navItems: ''
  },
  created: function() {
    var _self = this;
    $.ajax({
      type :'GET',
      url: 'http://1390.iluckycat.com/api/parent/class',
      success: function(data) {
        _self.navItems = data.data;
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    mouseOver: function(){

    }
  }
})
```

i completed the primary nav, but aboout the secondary nav i have no idea, this is the Json[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is your code for the secondary navigation?

Comment: No secondary navigation,i don't how to do it.

Comment: Why not code it like your main navigation?

Comment: How to get the json

Comment: You're using an AJAX call to get the primary navigation.  Can you use another AJAX call to get the secondary navigation data?

Comment: The primary navigation json data had the gc_id and the secondary navigation json address will use it ,like the 1057